# Tensorflow custom models inheritance and super()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Looking at tensorflow tutorials, I came across two different versions of creating custom models, in one you pass your custom child class to the `super()`, [like here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compute_loss). But also [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing#the_model_class), they do not pass anything to `super()`.

Below is a code example of what I mean. What is the difference? Is it just old vs new version of Python syntax?

```
class ResNet(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, num_classes):
    super().__init__()
    # or 
    # super(ResNet, self).__init__()
```

I tried running both variants with a small version of custom ResNet18, and in both cases it worked and achieved very similar results.

Answer (score 0):

For your case `super().__init__()` and `super(ResNet, self).__init__()` are the same. Starting from the ResNet class the code tries to find an init function within the parent class. But you can alter the arguments of `super()` to search for a specific function starting in the "grandparent" class.

Here is a minimal example, where the `calc`-function of two different parents is used:

```
class MyAdult():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def calc(self, b):
        return self.a * b


class MyChild(MyAdult):
    def calc(self, b):
        return self.a + b

    
class MyGrandchild(MyChild):
    def new_calc0(self, b, c):
        # super will look for "calc" in the next parent class -> "MyChild"
        return super().calc(b) + c

def new_calc1(self, b, c):
    # super will look for "calc" in the parents of MyChild -> "MyAdult"
    return super(MyChild, self).calc(b) + c

mgc = MyGrandchild(2)
print(mgc.new_calc0(4, 1))
print(mgc.new_calc1(4, 1))
```

Output:

```
7
9
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!